# How to pass a variable from one method to another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component called TopicsList in which there is a variable called topicsID inside onClick method. I would like to pass variable to render method topicsID={topicsID} however its giving undefined error.

```
var TopicsList = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            isTopicClicked : false,
            topicPages
        };
    },

    onClick: function (topicID) {
        this.setState({isTopicClicked : true});
        var topicsID = topicID;
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row topic-list">
                    <SingleTopicBox 
                        topicID="1" 
                        onClick={this.onClick} 
                        label="Topic"
                        />
                    <SingleTopicBox 
                        topicID="2" 
                        onClick={this.onClick} 
                        label="Topic"
                        />
                    <SingleTopicBox 
                        topicID="3" 
                        onClick={this.onClick} 
                        label="Topic"
                        />
                    <SingleTopicBox 
                        topicID="4" 
                        onClick={this.onClick} 
                        label="Topic"
                        />
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                { this.state.isTopicClicked ? <SelectedTopicPage topicsID={topicsID} topicPages={topicPages} /> : null }
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Please specify "undefined error". What exactly is the error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var` is something which only exists in that (lexical) scope - i.e *inside* your `onClick` function (and any nested functions).

You should either assign it to `this` i.e. `this.topicsID`. Or, in this case it looks like you're better off setting it on the state as you want to re-render your child Component.

```
onClick = (topicID) => {
  this.setState({ topicsID });
},

render() {
   const { topicsID } = this.state;
   return (
     <div>
       {topicsID && <SelectedTopicPage topicsID={topicsID} topicPages={topicPages} /> }
     </div>
   );
}
```